# Sums and permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $\sigma \in S_n \;$ then $\; \sum_{i=1}^n|\sigma(i)-i|\;$ is an even number.
I tried to show the statement for cyclic permutations first. However, I am not getting anywhere.
 The statement is trivial for transposition $(k,l)$. That´s all what I have found out so far.
 Can someone give me a hint why the statement is in fact true for any cyclic permutation ?

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is an integer, then $x$ and $|x|$ have the same parity (they are both even or both odd).

It follows that $\sum_{i=1}^n|\sigma(i)-i|$ has the same parity as $\sum_{i=1}^n(\sigma(i)-i)$.

Answer (score 1):

André's answer is essentially the definition of *slick*. But if you're into a more visceral approach, let's just look at a cycle like $\sigma = (1\,5\,2\,3\,4) \in S_5$, say.

Think of it in terms of a mapping like

$$1 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 1.$$

Now, note the claim is true if, as we move down the permutation, the parity changes an even number of times.

Given that the cycle loops back on itself, can you think of a nice reason this should be true?