# sum of absolute differences $|\sigma(i)-i|$ is even

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have to show that for all $\sigma \in S_n$ following equation holds:
$\sum_{i=1}^n|\sigma(i)-i|=2k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have no idea how to show it and would be very grateful for any hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums and permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625545/sums-and-permutation) – found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%7C%5Csigma(i)-i%7C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n|\sigma(i)-i|$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n(\sigma(i)-i)$ have the same parity, and the latter is easy to calculate.

Comment: Please search for dupes before answering, and close duplicate questions prior to answering.  Please see Martin R's comment below the question.  If you really *must* answer, then answer the duplicated question, after searching for dupes, and when found, closing duplicating questions.